# Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type text/php

Tags: javascript, php, iframe

I know there are a lot of questions about this Chrome error but I haven't seen anything for the MIME type text/php so here we go...

I'm having a headache of a problem. I have a very simple index.html as follows...

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Event List</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h3>Happening</h3>
    <iframe src="events.php" frameborder="0"></iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

The src from the iframe is set to a php file that uses curl to pull a JSON object from an API and displays it using Javascript. The script isn't running though. The iframe just shows the source code.

The Chrome console log error is as following...
**Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type text/php:**

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Does `events.php` produce `<html>` and `<body>` tags? Have you tried to load directly `events.php`? It should give the same result because it's probably a server-side (PHP) problem, not one of `iframe`.

Comment: How are you serving the PHP script? Are you running a web server? Does it have a PHP interpreter installed?

Comment: Ugh, well it was a nice surprise to find that my Apache server wasn't started properly which is why the PHP wasn't being interpreted. Thank you for asking your additional questions, leading me to find the all-too-simple solution :)